# The flux over the surface of a cube and the integral of the divergence over that cube are not the same (Divergence Theorem)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm sure I've made a trivial error but I cannot spot it.

Fix R>0
Consider the cube $C_R$ as the cube from (0,0,0) to (R,R,R) (save me from listing the 8 vertices)

Consider $S_R$ as the surface of $C_R$

Consider the vector field $v:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$
given by $v(x,y,z) = (3x+z^2,2y,R-z)$

**Part 1**

Calculate $\nabla.v$

$\nabla.v=\frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{v_y}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{v_z}}{\partial{z}}=3+2-1=4$

**Part 2**

Calculate $\iiint_{C_R}\nabla.vdV$

$=\int_0^R\int_0^R\int_0^R4dxdydz$

This is trivial it is $=4R^3$

**Part 3**

Calculate the flux $\iint_{S_R}v.ndA$ where n is the unit normal to $S_R$ at the point.

Every keystroke is lagging now.

I did this by doing it over all 6 sides of the cube. The normals are trivial and the sides look like $R(1,s,t)$ for $s,t\in[0,1]$ (this is the right side) or $R(0,s,t)$ which is the left side.

I'm not even sure how you'd get an $R^3$ in there, I can provide more working if needed but it really isn't hard.

What have I done? Is this result right and perhaps I have misunderstood something?

**Addendum**

I think my error may come from my parameter ranges, I should be going from 0 to R not 0 to 1. This is essentially a substitution where I didn't multiply by the rate of that substitution with respect to the thing it replaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You can do
$$\iint_{S_R} v\cdot n\ dA = \int_0^R \int_0^R v(0,x',y') \cdot -e_1 + v(R, x', y') \cdot e_1 + v(x', 0, y')\cdot-e_s + \ldots dx' dy'$$
The double integral will yield a $R^2$-like term and the integrand should give another (By Gauss, the results of (1) and (2) should be equal).

---

$$\begin{align*}
v(0,s,t) \cdot -e_1 & = -t^2 \\
v(R,s,t) \cdot +e_1 & = 3R + t^2 \\
v(s,0,t) \cdot -e_2 & = 0 \\
v(s,R,t) \cdot +e_2 & = 2R \\
v(s,t,0) \cdot -e_3 & = -R \\
v(s,t,R) \cdot +e_3 & = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \iint_{S_R} v\cdot n\ dA & = \iint_{(0,0)}^{(R,R)} 4R\ ds\ dt = 4R^3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: It's a homework question I've gotten wrong, it's lead me through the hoops, I must do as it asks. Thanks for trying though. I'm actually trying to find my error.

Comment: @AlecTeal What exaclty have you gotten wrong? I didn't see any mistake in the question so far...

Comment: I think going over 0 to 1 is my error, I should be going over 0 to R (or integrate with respect to dRs and dRt if that makes any sense)

Comment: @AlecTeal no, that's perfectly okay. You'll need to apply the transformation formula correctly, though. This will yield
$$R^2 \iint_{(0,0)}^{(1,1)} v(0, Rs', Rt') + \ldots\ ds'\ dt'$$
Where the $R^2$ comes from $\frac{dt}{dt'} \cdot \frac{ds}{ds'}$

Comment: note, I had a mistake in $v(R,s,t) = 3R+t^2$ - it all works fine now. Also, the integrand, if combined like I suggested, is a constant, so the scaling of the arguments of $v$ has no impact other than the factor of $R^2$ being added, thus resulting in
$$R^2 \iint_{(0,0)}^{(1,1)} 4R\ ds'\ dt' = 4R^3$$
as well.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the integral over the side $z=R$ is $0$, while the integral over
$z=0$ is $-R^3$ (integrating $-R$ over a square of side $R$).